# why is the continue out of loop for my bubble sort code and how do i fix the problem/ why is the bubble_sort(undefined)

Tags: python, break, continue

```
`def bubble_sort(numbers):
# We set swapped to True so the loop looks runs at least once
swapped = True
while swapped:
    swapped = False
    for i in range(len(numbers) - 1):
        if numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1]:
            # Swap the elements
            numbers[i], numbers[i + 1] = numbers[i + 1], numbers[i]
            # Set the flag to True so we'll loop again
            swapped = True

      results = bubble_sort(numbers)
      UserInput = input("Please enter ten integer numbers with a space 
      in between, or 'Quit' to exit: ")
      numbers = UserInput.split()
      print(UserInput)
      while True:
        if UserInput.lower() == 'quit':

        break

       if not UserInput.isdigit():
         print("Invalid input.")

      continue

      else:
        print(results)`
```

In my code, the bubble_sort(numbers)gets an error stating it's undefined. What is the reason for this? any amount of help is appreciated.

Comment: your formatting is all over the place. Remember in Python that whitespace, tabs, etc. have meaning.

Comment: What makes you think it is *not* "out of loop"?

Comment: the section `if not UserInput.isdigit()` is not aligned. `else` is not aligned to `if` and `continue` is not aligned to `print`

Answer (score 0):

There are many sections in your code that is not aligned correctly. I am giving you one of the example.

This section of your code is not aligned.

```
if not UserInput.isdigit():
  print("Invalid input.")

    continue #should be aligned to print statement

 else: #not aligned. Should be aligned to if statement
  print(results)
```

The above code should be as follows:

```
if not UserInput.isdigit():
   print("Invalid input.")

   continue

else:
   print(results)
```

Please review all the sections of your code and ensure they are aligned.